# Is 000,000,000.00 greater than zero?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mask

I have an input mask on my text box like

```
        000,000,000.00
```

I have the following jQuery code to check the value of text box before submitting data.

```
    var txt_box = $('#txt_box').attr('value');

     if(txt_box <= 0 )
```

But now even if I didn't input any data, the box remains empty with only the input mask, 
data is submitting.

Comment: what an amazing title

Comment: dear if u leave all this Criticism and reply to question, i should appricate this...

Comment: Yeah. Who downvotes this? It's a perfectly fine question.

Comment: I fixed the spelling slightly, if it's not what you meant to say feel free to roll back.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**First**: Separating floating points with a `dot notation` is required.

**Second**: You are checking for `equal or less` not just `less than`.

**Third**: Use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` to convert that input string into a `Number`.

Example:

```
var txt_box = $('#txt_box').attr('value').replace(/,/g, ".");
    if(parseFloat(txt_box) <= 0 )
```

Answer (score 3):

You use `<=` instead `<` 
Anyway, you should parse `value` to number too.